# Internet Explorer 9 Title bar, the url of the page is display before page title

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer, microsoft-dynamics-crm, internet-explorer-9

All,

I am having an issue where our ie9 on server2008R2 is displaying the url of the page before the actual title.  I would prefer that this information is swapped.  On a windows 7 enterprise N machine (with ie9) it is displayed properly with the title of the page first.

I have attempted to sort through the registry and look for an option to switch this behavior.  I have done my fair share of Google searches, and I have checked the registry and group policy.

The program I am explicitly having this problem in , is Microsoft CRM 4.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You,

Josh

Answer (score 1):

We had the url being prepended on the title and found we could disabled it by changing the following setting from `Disabled` to `Enabled`:

`Internet Options` - `Sequrity Settings` - `Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints`

Comment: Tested this is on IE9 as well, Gordon is correct. This was the only place where I found this answer as well. I was able to get the address and status bar to be hidden using a vbs, but had to use Gordon's method to get rid of the embedded URL in the title bar. Thanks

Comment: As unrelated as it seems this was the fix for our CRM v4 deployment as well.